# Expected number of different faces in multiple die roles

Tags: probability, dice

I roll 6 6-sided regular dice. What is the expected number of unique up-facing sides I will find among those dice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to calculate the probability you will see one particular number, then use the linearity of expectation to multiply by $6$.  What is the chance you see a $1$ with six dice?

Comment: E(seeing a N in six dice rolls) = 6*(1/6) = 1 so your saying E(seeing all numbers) = E(seeing a one) + E(seeing a two)... so E(seeing all numbers) = 6E(seeing a N) = 6 Clear and concise. Thanks! +1

Comment: The very good hint was used incorrectly in the comment above.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Please elaborate!

Comment: @DoubleAA:  The chance that you see a $1$ is not $1$.  You can certainly have rolls like $222222$ that don't have any $1$'s.  The expected number of $1$'s is $1$, but that counts $111111$ as $6$.  We want to count it as only yes-1 roll that has a one.  So what is the chance you see a $1$ with six dice?

Comment: @RossMillikan 1- (5/6)^6 no? But aren't I looking for expected value?

Comment: @DoubleAA:  That is correct, and is the expected value of the variable (1=see at least one 1, 0=see no 1).  The expected number of different faces is now six times this because each separate face is seen with this probability.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ahhh so changing the first part of my above comment to: E(seeing a N in six dice rolls) = 1- (5/6)^6 and then the final number to 6 times that works.

Comment: Let $X_i=1$ if you see an $i$ at some time, $0$ otherwise. Then $E(X_i)=\Pr(X_i=1)$. This is a property of Bernoulli random variables. Probability and expectation are equal.